# Linking summations with their correct function(s)

Tags: functions, summation, logarithms, asymptotics

Guys can you please guide me step by step on how to link given functions with the functions to choose from. So for example a function $g(n)\in \Theta n^2$ and if there is no match then you say there is no match. The problem is that I did some of the exercises by guessing, but I would like to know how to link these summations with their correct functions mathematically.

$f(n) = \Sigma^n_{i=1}\Sigma^i_{j=1} 1$


 
$i(n) = \Sigma^n_{i=1}[4 + log(n)]$


**Choose from:**

$log_2(n)$


$n$


$n log_2(n)$


$n (log_2(n))^2$


$n^2$


$n^2 log_2(n)$


$n^3$


$2^n$


$2^{2n}$


$n!$


$n^n$


no match

Answer (score 0):

$$f(n) =\sum^n_{i=1}\sum^i_{j=1} 1=\sum^n_{i=1}i=\frac {n(n+1)}2 $$

$$i(n) = \sum^n_{i=1}[4 + \log(n)]= n(4 + \log n)$$